General question about navigation
I have scene inside a room. When blender tries to navigate around this room so I can influence my character in it, blender slows the zoom down and even dislocates my last position to accommodate for this room which I don't care for.  Is there a way I can tell blender to ignore this room and navigate normally?

See the part about Auto Depth here
